# Change the href for a hyperlink by using its value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I got the idea If I want change the anchor tag href by matching an anchor with a specific existing href, I wrote below code that is working:

```
<a href="Accept.php">Accept</a>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("a[href='Accept.php']").attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
</script>
```

But Now I was working on to change the hyperlink by using the anchor tag value using jQuery.

I wrote below code for that but it's not working for me.

```
$("a[text='Accept']").attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
```

Comment: There is no text attribute on the anchor tag. So you cannot do `$("a[text='Accept']")`

Comment: If your `a` elements don't have a `text` attribute (and they shouldn't, it's invalid HTML), `a[text='...']` isn't going to work.

Comment: It would help a **lot** to know what the HTML looks like for your desired version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a").filter(function(){

return $(this).text() == 'Accept';
}).attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="Accept.php">Accept</a>
```

1. use filter and return the anchor you want to select.
2. then use `attr()` to set the attr value

Comment: Bro, Thank you So Much.
Among Of All the Answers. Your ans was perfect.

Comment: @DoeChalie glad to help mate happy coding

Comment: can you also tell me how i can do it in php ? let suppose i have a variable that contain some code of html page , and i want to filter from it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. It is working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a:contains('Accept')").attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="Accept.php">Accept</a>
```

Comment: setting new text to an anchor and putting attribute value is different from selecting an anchor with a specific text

Comment: @guradio, yes you are right. But he wants to change anchor tag using the value that's why I prefer to do this in a simple way.

Comment: Bro, Just do little bit changes Please.

Comment: It is changing all the anchor tag to accept and with same href.

Comment: i just want to change the href who has value just accept nothing else.

Comment: yeah @DoeChalie. Thanks. It was my mistake. I changed it.

Comment: still you did not change it

Answer (score 0):

If your `a` elements don't have a `text` attribute (and they shouldn't, it's invalid HTML), `a[text='...']` isn't going to work.

If you're trying to set their `href` to their *contents*, you could use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), but note that it matches anywhere in the element:

```
$("a:contains('Accept')").attr("href", function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Note that that uses the version of `attr` [accepting a callback](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), so it uses the specific text of each `a` as the attribute.

Your content would need to be a valid relative or absolute URL, e.g. `<a>Accept.php</a>`. or similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can use contains selector to get link object. refer https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("a:contains('Accept')).attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, jQuery does not allow to select elements by the contents of their inner text. You will need to either filter the results or use a different approach altogether.

First, let's see the filtering option. You will need to select all anchor tags and filter them by their contents afterwards using the `filter()` function:

```
$("a")
    .filter(function(idx, el) {
        return $(el).text() === "Accept";
    })
    .attr("href", "http://www.accept.com");
```

[Same example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/askohaa9/).

However, this is obviously a rather slow option and on very large pages, it might turn out to be causing a perceivable lag. Make sure it doesn't cause trouble for you before pushing this to production.

An alternative approach, and the recommended one, would be to use a class or id. As you know, jQuery, as well as vanilla JS, is able to select elements by their id or class. I would suggest trying to figure out if you can apply an id/class to your link and select that instead. Use the filtering approach as a last resort solution.

Answer (score -2):

Here is sample [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/milanchheda/vbwurpbw/1/) code for you:

HTML:

```
<a href="Accept.php">Accept</a>
```

JQuery:

```
if($("a").text() == 'Accept') {
    $("a").attr('href', 'http://www.accept.com');
}
```

Comment: And if there's more than one `a` element?

Comment: Well, in that case, we can change the code. Assign class and custom attribute to each <a> tag and based on that, we can tweak the JQuery code. 

Current solution is given based on the mentioned code in the question.